# Quart in combination with NATS.io client

Tags: python-asyncio, nats.io, quart

I am trying to run QUART and NATS client in one application. Using this code for nats part `[https://github.com/nats-io/stan.py/issues/12#issuecomment-400865266][1]`

My main function contains:

```
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(serve(app, config))
    loop.run_until_complete(run_nats(loop))
    loop.close()
```

But it just runs QUART and nats is blocked. How can I solve this?

Information:

- Python 3.9
- asyncio-nats-client 0.11.4
- Quart 0.11.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `loop.run_until_complete` line will run and block until it completes, in this case running first Quart (until it completes) and then nats. To run both concurrently I typically run use [gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather),

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(serve(app, config), run_nats(loop))
```